# Verilog: Cross module reference for pure functions

Tags: verilog, fpga

Are pure (only accessing input regs) functions synthesizable when they are accessed as a cross module reference?

Example:

```
// a module with functions inside
module functions;
  function fn1;
  input reg i;
    fn1 = i;
  endfunction
endmodule

// must be synthesizable vvv 
module consumer(input i, output o);
   functions fns();
   assign o = fns.fn1(i);
endmodule
```

Comment: You might want to look at a SystemVerilog `package` where you can define a function inside the package and then import the package into your module. Most synthesis tools support this.

Comment: @dave_59 I am asking about Verilog not SystemVerilog, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly synthesizable because a pure function gets in-lined into the combinatorial logic inside the the calling module. There are no cross-module reference to any signals after that. But many synthesis tools haven chosen not to handle any kind of cross-module reference, even if the hierarchy gets flattened.

In SystemVerilog you would define a function inside a `package` and then `import` the package into your module. Any synthesis tools that supports the most basic SystemVerilog constructs also supports this.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible in Verilog. (yes, that's the complete answer ffs)

Comment: Don't use a condescending tone.